# How to change Android Home Screen Orientation for other apps

Tags: java, android

I just bought a Galaxy S5 which does not have the inate ability to put the home icons in landscape mode. I also bought a kenwood dash gps/radio which connects to my phone and puts the phones screen on my dash with the help of a kenwood app and an mhl cable. The home screen on the dash is tiny. It needs to be displayed in landscape. I tried athe ultimate screen rotation app but once it connects to the kenwood then the home screen is brought out of horizontal back into vertical. Having done a few android apps I wondered if it is possible to force the home screen horizontally and override other apps. I could just write my own but am having trouble finding this specific ability.

Comment: You cannot force other people's apps to be put into a certain screen orientation.  I would say the majority of apps are only designed for one or the other and doing so would probably break the application if you were to do so.

Comment: What I meant was can I force the home screen horizontal and is there am option to prevent other apps from changing it while my app is running

Comment: So you have an application that makes the home-screen landscape against the S5 normal orientation, but when connected to the vehicle it reverts it back to portrait (even though it wants to display it as horizontal).  I would assume it does some sort of a check internally to see if your device is landscape supported and makes its own decision.  You might not be able to deal with that.  I don't think another ROM would help if that is what they are doing.  Probably best to try on the Kenwood forums to see what users are experiencing there.

Comment: Ok, appreciate the advice.